# Нашел какой то код в паблике, решил попробовать, столкнулся с проблемой

Tags: python

Нашел какой то код в паблике, решил попробовать, столкнулся с проблемой 
`"message": "invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 7)",`

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

date_when_we_meating = datetime(2016, 5, 13)

def diff_dates(meating_date):
return abs(datetime.now()-meating_date).seconds

def print_i_love_you(meating_date):
print("я ❤ тебя уже {} секунд".format(diff_dates(meating_date)))

while True:
print_i_love_you(date_when_we_meating)
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отступы строк в коде на Python имеют значение. Отступ означает вложенность кода в какой-то блок - например, вложенность в функцию или в цикл. Если вы где-то увидели код на Python, где после строк, заканчивающихся на двоеточия, нет строк с отступами, просите чтобы выложили например на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) код в нормальном виде - без отступов такой код не будет работать. В данном случае можно догадаться, какими были отступы изначально, но это возможно не всегда.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

date_when_we_meating = datetime(2016, 5, 13)

def diff_dates(meating_date):
    return abs(datetime.now()-meating_date).seconds

def print_i_love_you(meating_date):
    print("я ❤ тебя уже {} секунд".format(diff_dates(meating_date)))

while True:
    print_i_love_you(date_when_we_meating)
    time.sleep(1)
```

В целом - прежде чем пробовать разбирать примеры на новом для себя языке программирования, желательно уже иметь какое-то представление о нем (например, прочитать несколько глав в книге по Python или в несколько уроков в каком-нибудь онлайн учебнике). Для данного примера нужно представление хотя бы о функциях и циклах.